# API GET Request test using Playwright

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, testing, playwright

I have been trying to verify the GET status using the following code. Unfortunately, I am getting an error "apiRequestContext.get: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8080". Any insight would be much appreciated.

**Code:**

```js
import { expect, test } from '@playwright/test';

test('Get health status', async ({ request }) => {
    const response = await request.get('http://localhost:8080/myapp/actuator/health')
    expect(response.status()).toBe(200)
  })
```

**Error:**
apiRequestContext.get: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8080

Comment: Are you able to hit this endpoint successfully using any other testing tool like postman and get the response as 200?

Comment: Can you try `await request.get('http://localhost:8080/myapp/actuator/health', verify=False)`

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since NodeJS 17, node will prefer [IPv6 over IPv4](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40537).

## Verification

It might be that the service only listens on IPv4, but the client uses IPv6. Check for the words `IPv4` or `IPv6` in:

- `netstat -tulpen` (on linux) or
- `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P 8080 | grep -i --color 8080` (on macOS).

## Solutions

There are two options:

1. Enable IPv6 binding for the service. This depends on your service framework - search `how to enable ipv6 for service XYZ` in Google.
2. Configure NodeJS to prefer IPv4 over IPV6. Add to `playwright.config.js`:

```js
import dns from "dns";
dns.setDefaultResultOrder("ipv4first");
```

3. If the service can handle, force the use of IPv4: connect to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` instead of `http://localhost:8080`
4. Disable the IPv6 address for localhost for the whole machine.
   Edit the hosts file (`sudo vi /etc/hosts`) and remove `::1             localhost`.

## Resources

- See https://blog.apify.com/ipv4-mapped-ipv6-in-nodejs/
- https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dnssetdefaultresultorderorder